# Python: Storing data in a text file and appending particular/individual lines

Tags: python, file-io

This is a computer science project that I've been working on.
Test scores are saved in a text file against a students name. for example:

```
Rob 21
Terry 12
Mike 33
```

I can get the program to do this but I want it to read the lines of the text file and identify if the name is already in existence. If so, it should add the next score onto the end of the line. If Terry takes the test again the scores should then read:

```
Rob 21
Terry 12 23
Mike 33
```

This is the relevant piece of code. It starts after the test is complete and the user has input their name, class and received their score.

```
import fileinput

print("Well done " +name+ ", your score is "+ (str(score)))

    entry = (name +" "+ (str(score)))


    if classchoice == "A": 
        classfile = open("classa.txt")
        for line in classfile:
            if name in line:
                oldline = line
                newline = (oldline+" "+(str(score)))
                print (newline)
                classfile.close()
            else:
                classfile = open("classb.txt","a")
                classfile.write(entry)
                classfile.write('\n')
                classfile.close()

        for line in fileinput.input("classa.txt", inplace=1):
            line = line.replace(oldline,newline)
            line = line.strip()
```

I'm having difficulty with this because:

1. The first part where it reads the lines in the files and finds the student name and results works but when I try to put the line together with the new score it ends up putting the new score underneath when it print (newline) so it looks like:

   Terry 12
   23
2. another issue is the else doesn't work. I get: local variable 'oldline' referenced before assignment

Could anyone help me with this. I'm new to python and this is a little overwhelming at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you read the file , and you get each line, it already has the `newline` (`\n`) at the end, so when you do -

```
newline = (oldline+" "+(str(score)))
```

`oldline` already has `\n` at the end. And hence you get something like - `Name oldscore\n newscoe` , and hence it comes on a new line.

You would need to strip off the previous newline before create the newline, Example -

```
newline = (oldline.rstrip()+" "+(str(score)))
```

--

Also, what you are doing seems to be very inefficient, you can directly use `fileinput.input()` for your case -

```
if classchoice == "A":
    write_flag = True
    with fileinput.input("classa.txt", inplace=1) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip()
            if name in line:
                line = line + " " + str(score)
                write_flag = False
            print(line)
        #This is if `name` was never found, meaning we have to add the name to the file with the score.
    if write_flag:
        with open("classa.txt",'a') as f:
            f.write("{} {}\n".format(name,score))
```

---

As indicated in the comments, using `in` would result in wrong entries getting updated. A way to overcome that would be to split the line and compare the first entry in the split -

```
if classchoice == "A":
    write_flag = True
    with fileinput.input("classa.txt", inplace=1) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip()
            words = line.split()
            if name == words[0]:
                line = line + " " + str(score)
                write_flag = False
            print(line)
        #This is if `name` was never found, meaning we have to add the name to the file with the score.
    if write_flag:
        with open("classa.txt",'a') as f:
            f.write("{} {}\n".format(name,score))
```

Comment: You're a genius! Only one issue, The if write_flag: followed by print(name, score) doesn't write to the file. I put my initial 4 lines from beneath my else statement into the code and it works now but I understand it isn't the most efficient method.  Is there a better way?

Comment: If you change your code to exactly what I gave, it would work, if may not be working if you just take parts of my code and replace in yours. Since when you do `print()` inside the block where `fileinput.input()` has not been closed, those lines go into the file (if `inplace=1`) is provided.

Comment: I copied and pasted it directly. The part where it searches the file for a previous student works perfectly and it adds the scores on just as I wanted it too. Thank you so much. The only part that isn't working seems to be the final part where it should enter a new student and their score print(name, score). I understand that it should work because it is still using the fileinput.input.

Comment: @mjolnir Please try the latest code I updated, seems like printing outside of `for line in f:` does not go into the `fileinput()` openned file .

Comment: Thank you very much. You nailed it!

Comment: Glad I could be of help :)

Comment: Excellent. That looks great too.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic and any logic using `in` is flawed and can harm your existing data, to see why:

infile:

```
 stephen 12
 paula 10

new_name, new_score = "paul",20

"paul" in "paula 10" -> True
```

infile after:

```
 stephen 12
 paula 10 20
```

Where is paul and why does paula now have two scores? Because you are matching substrings not exact names.

You are also using the wrong structure to store the data, use a dict with json:

To create the dict initially from your file use:

```
import csv
import json


with open("in.txt") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
    dct = {row[0]: row[1:] for row in r}
```

Then dump it to the file:

```
with open("in.txt", "w") as out:
    json.dump(dct, out)
```

When you want to add new data just `json.load` and access using the key to add data or adding a new key/value pairing if the name does not exist:

```
new_name, new_score = "Terry", 20

with open("in.txt") as f:
    dct = json.load(f)
    dct[new_name] = new_score if new_name not in dct else dct[new_name] + [new_score]

with open("in.txt", "w") as out:
    json.dump(dct, out)
```

in.txt will contain your updated data:

```
 {"Mike": ["33"], "Rob": ["21"], "Terry": ["12", 20]}
```

If you are going to use a regular file then the correct approach is to check the name not using `in`, you can use a tempfile and shutil.move t0 update the original file:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import csv
new_name, new_score = "Terry", 20
with open("in.txt") as f, NamedTemporaryFile("w",dir=".", delete=False) as out:
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
    wr = csv.writer(out, delimiter=" ")
    found = False
    for row in r:
        # actually check the name for an exact match
        if row[0] == new_name:
            wr.writerow(row + [new_score])
            found = True
        else:
            wr.writerow(row)
    # if name is new, found will still be False
    if not found:
        wr.writerow([new_name, new_score])

# replace original file with updated
move(out.name, "in.txt")
```

Which will output:

```
Rob 21
Terry 12 20
Mike 33
Terry 20
```

Comment: This looks interesting and I hadn't considered it. I'm going to have a play with this and see how it goes. I might get back to you if I need a little help. Cheers.

Comment: @mjolnir, your current approach and the accepted answer are both flawed, `in` is not how to check for an exact match in a string

Comment: Honestly, I'm really happy with the help from both of you. Thank you both. I'd be stuffed without the support.

Comment: @mjolnir, using `in` is the wrong approach, it will match names incorrectly and completely screw your data file as I have shown in my answer. I would highly recommend you do not use the answer you accepted unless you want the wrong result. It is simply wrong

Comment: I completely understand the issue regarding Paula, Paul, Pauline, etc all being identified by the same `if name in line` issue. It would cause a big problem if that were to come up and your way is technically better but i'm slowly learning and I need to get my head around the way you've used (is it a dict?) to store the data from the text file. I was going to ask another question about how I could go about sorting the individual students scores in order of highest to lowest, and also an average, and I would imagine the way you structured the layout of the data would be useful here.

Comment: do you mean the single highest score?

Comment: If so, you can sort with something like `sorted(dct.items(),key=lambda x: max(x[1],key=int),reverse=True)`

Comment: essentially, the list of students should be output in order of highest score to lowest score which may mean sorting individual students scores in column order first to make the comparison. They also need to be averaged but i'm still working on that.

Comment: well using the above on your first sample input if it were already json would return `('Mike', ['33']), ('Rob', ['21']), ('Terry', ['12'])]`, using `max` will make it work for multiple scores also